# What am I doing wrong with CSS font-face URL?

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

I am trying to get this font "Albermarle Swash" to appear but after searching the internet for answers I can't find any answers. Does anybody know what I am doing wrong?? I am using Chrome, tried it on FF and IE and still no good.

```
@font-face { 
  font-family: 'AlbermarleSwash';
  src: url('http://ensabahone.000webhostapp.com/fonts/AlbemarleSwash.ttf') format('truetype');
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'AlbermarleSwash';
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6vURk/11/

I've also tried, and no luck:

```
<link href='http://ensabahone.000webhostapp.com'; rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Comment: download the font and give as internal link, It may work

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_font-face_rule

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is cross origin problem and also you need to convert the font into web font for better support of all devices, you can go through https://transfonter.org/

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Albemarle Swash';
    src: url('AlbemarleSwash.eot');
    src: url('AlbemarleSwash.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('AlbemarleSwash.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('AlbemarleSwash.woff') format('woff'),
        url('AlbemarleSwash.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('AlbemarleSwash.svg#AlbemarleSwash') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I just looked at your fiddle and noticed cross origin errors...  Cross origin doesn't allow you to access other websites from your own to avoid click baiting and other malicious techniques (JSONP, among others being exceptions).  I would recommend downloading the file and uploading it to your own server and using it locally.

**Sum up**:  You can't use this file while it's on the other web host because of cross origin policies.  Just download it and upload it to your own web server.